# Linq query with multiple where's

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying the to query my Status Update repository using the following

```
    var result = (from s in _dataContext.StatusUpdates
                  where s.Username == "friend1" && s.Username == "friend2" etc...
                  select s).ToList();
```

Instead of using `s.Username == "friendN"` continuously is there anyway I can pass a list or array or something like that rather that specifying each one, or can I use a foreach loop in the middle of the query.

Thanks

Comment: sorry, autocomments would be cool tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to check whether the `Username` property has some specified value, you can create a list of the values and then use method such as `All` or `Any` to check if some condition holds for any/all elements of the array.

Your example looks a bit suspicious though - the user name `s.Username` cannot be equal to multiple different strings. Did you want to check whether it is equal to any of the (specified) names? That could be written like this:

```
var friends = new[] { "friend1", "friend2", ... };
var result = 
  from s in dc.StatusUpdates 
  where friends.Any(fr => s.Username == fr)
  select s;
```

This returns all status updates such that the `Username` property is equal to any of the specified friend names (specified as an array, but you could use any `IEnumerable<string>`).

Comment: sweet, thanks for this excellent answer mate, worked like a treat. I am a student and new to linq so just trying to get my head around some of the new syntax.

I like the way you wrote this friends.Any(fr => s.Username == fr)... very easy to read and understand what is happening but not sure if i would have found it on my own:( thanks for the help

Comment: LINQ is quite flexible, especially when using extension methods explititly. Some good resources with more information are 101 LINQ samples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx and a list of extension methods (such as `Any`): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yo could do it like this:

```
IQueryable<s> query= _dataContext.StatusUpdates;
foreach (var item in names)
{
    query = query.Where(p=>p.Username == item);
}
List<s> result = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I mucked with some data types of yours but this should be close:

```
    var names = new List<string>();
    // populate names

    var updates = new List<StatusUpdate>();
    // populate updates

    var result = (from s in updates
          where names.Contains(s.ToString())
          select s).ToList();
```